# Kendo dropdown width

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi can someone tell me how to set width for kendo dropdown? Here is my code sample and it is not working. Anything wrong in that?

```
$("#div1").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: items,
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    Width : "250px"
});
```

Comment: Since my answer isn't working for you, please show us your relevant code, namely: JS (this is what you have), CSS and HTML. Additionaly, make a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The kendoDropDownList does not have a property width for it's configuration. See here: [Kendo Docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist)

What you can do, is styling the correct class.
Since you hopefully do know where your dropdown lies, you can specify the selector so it doesn't apply to all dropdowns.

```
#myContainer .k-dropdown {
     width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: When I try to apply class, it is applying for all dropdowns

Comment: This doesn't change the width of the dropdown popup (ie the popup that opens when you click the dropdown)

Comment: It should also change the width of the popup as seen here: http://dojo.telerik.com/eXOce. Is this not the case for you? Maybe open a new question then! :)

Comment: Does not work for me. The approach of $("#div1").width(250).kendoDropDownList({.. works fine.

Answer (score 15):

In case you have to give different width to different controls you can follow the below approach for giving the width to the specific control.

```
$("#div1").width(250).kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: items,
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id",
})
```

Answer (score 12):

If MVC Razor DropDownList HTML helper/wrapper syntax is applied, then you can use method HtmlAttributes to specify the width of dropdown list like:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()                                                            .Name("myDDL")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:100px" })
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this as well;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var kendoDropDown = $('#div1').data('kendoDropDownList');
    kendoDropDown.list.width(250);
  });
</script>
```

Further documentation can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/dropdownlist/overview#customize-the-width-of-the-dropdownlist) in Telerik's official API reference.

Answer (score 2):

Better to do it with CSS

```
#div1 {     
    width: 250px;
}
```

But will work with code

```
$("#div1").width(250).kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: items,
    dataTextField: "Name",
   dataValueField: "Id",
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the automatic width set by the browser:

```
$("select").each(function () {
    $(this)
        .width($(this).width())
        .kendoDropDownList();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work 100% as it has worked for me, I tried the above solution, it did not work for me so I found this on my own :), I hope you all benefit from this

```
#DivThatContainsTheDropdown .k-combobox{
width: 22em !important;
}
```